# Skype installs, but test call fails in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, skype

Skype installs fine using command:

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

and I could type text messages with my friends in skype,but I could not make any video calls (`my webcam logitech c270` is fine---it works great with `guvcview` application). I can't even make the test call to the skype echo service...it just says "call failed".

I removed and reinstalled skype using command:

```
sudo apt-get remove skype
```

and the same thing kept happening. What is going on?

[UPDATE]
   So even though the Skype test call service fails....actual calls with other people work fine. So no complaints--its not like I wanted to have a conversation with the robot anyways.